# VisualStudioでMicrosoftReportを使うまで

Tags: c#, visual-studio

お世話になります。

VisualStudio Community 2017で、C#でWindows.FormによるReport(MicrosoftReportingService)を使用したいと思っています。インストールも完了し、rdlcにコントロールを張り付け、いざフォーム上にReportViewerを載せようとしたのですが、ツールボックスの中にはそれに対応する項目がありません。

サイト様を見る限りでは、『Reporting』というグループの中に含まれているとのことらしいのですが、それらの項目すら見当たりません。現在では別の名前か何かになっているのでしょうか？

お力添えを頂ければ幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

何故かReportingってカテゴリが無くなってますね。
多分Visual C# アイテムの直下には、レポートとレポートウィザードがありますよ。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ですが、新規に用意するときではなく、作成したReportをフォームに貼り付けるときです。自作したユーザコントロールなどは、ビルドしたときにーるボックスに追加されますけど、このReportは作った後の追加ができません。何か見落としているだけでしょうか？

Comment: ツールボックスなら自分で追加できます。
[全般]を右クリックして、[アイテムの選択]-[.Net Framework コンポーネント]-[参照]
参照場所はNuGetでもらってきた Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winformsなら
[プロジェクトディレクトリ]\packages\Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms.15xxx.xx\lib\net40 にMicrosoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll があります。

Comment: ご回答していただいたのですが、やはりうまくいきません…。自分で作成した『Report1.rdlc』というコントロールを張り付けたいのですが、それが出てきません。教えていただいたツールボックスは新しいコントロールは貼りつけてくれますが、通常ならツールボックスの最上部に表示されるはずの自作コントロールが出てこないのです。

Comment: rdlcはコントロールじゃないですよ。https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms252067.aspx?

Comment: すみません、なんか勘違いしていたようです。もう一度見直してみようと思います。ご迷惑をおかけしました。